# Why XMLBeanDeclaration returning null object after passing xml file?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, initialization, connection

```
ISReportMain(XMLConfiguration config) {
    this.config = config;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String configFile = args[0];
    XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration();
    try {
        config.load(configFile);
        ISReportMain report = new ISReportMain(config);
        report.run();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Report failed to run", ex);
    }
}

private void run() throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet results = null;
    XMLBeanDeclaration decl = new XMLBeanDeclaration(config, "dataSource");
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) BeanHelper.createBean(decl);
    ....
    ....
}
```

In above code I pass physical path of xml file in run configuration. xml file contains database connection details.

But on 'XMLBeanDeclaration decl' initialization it returns null object,  which results in susequent intializations to fail.

Edit:

As an argument i'm passing :
    `C:\Users\dev\workspace\Reporting\conf\integration\subscribers.xml`

Stacktrace:

Currently it doesnt throw exception, instead it sets 'decl' as null object and further dataconnection throws exception because of decl null value.

[Value of decl after this line - XMLBeanDeclaration decl = new XMLBeanDeclaration(config, "dataSource");](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr4kg.png)

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please let me know if you need extra details.

Comment: could u pls give the arguments u passing to the program and the stacktrace?

Comment: @mattymanme - I have added description as per your request in question details. Let me know if you need anything.